# Desire2Learn API does not return data

Tags: api, desire2learn

I'm using D2L’s API sample site to test out their API before I begin any development and I have noticed a few issues. When I request to be authenticated, I am redirected to our D2L instance to login. However, I am not redirected back to the sample site after authenticating. If I return to the sample site and authenticate again, then the user id and key are populated because of my D2L session. But when I request "get versions", no data is returned or if I request "who am I", I get a "Invalid JSON primitive" because the sample site is expecting to format a string from the response but there is nothing in the response. Anyone out there have a solution for this?

Comment: Can you please let us know which language version of the API sample you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Your report seems like it could indicate that your back-end service is not respecting the `&x_target=appURL` parameter passed in at the end of the [first stage of the authentication process](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/basic/auth.html). Perhaps your back-end service needs to support the deep linking required to redirect back to a passed in target parameter URL?